# Onclick event not changing element ID

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, styling

I'm attempting to code a slide-puzzle in the browser. When the user clicks a square on the grid that's adjacent to the BLANK square, the clicked square should be swapped with the BLANK.

EDIT: This is what it should do when finished: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle

I'm trying to achieve this using onclick triggers to call a JavaScript function that first checks if the square is a valid move, then switches the ID attribute of the square. My CSS file contains the image for each square, linked to the square's ID.

As it stands, the squares do nothing when clicked.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Puzzle.css">
  <title>Fifteen Puzzle</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Puzzle.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startPuzzle()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square" id="square0" onclick="A.slide(0, 0, this.id)"> </div>
    <div class="square" id="square1" onclick="A.slide(1, 0, this.id)">  </div>
    <div class="square" id="square2" onclick="A.slide(2, 0, this.id)">  </div>
/* And so on to the 16th square: */
    <div class="square" id="squareBLANK" onclick="A.slide(3, 3, this.id)">  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE:

```
class Puzzle {
    constructor () {
    this.board = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, "_"]];
    }

    slide (i, j, a){
        x = this.board[i][j];
        if (this.board[i+1][j] == "_") {
            this.board[i+1][j] = x;
            this.board[i][j] = "_";
            document.getElementById(a).id = "PLACEHOLDER";
            document.getElementById("squareBLANK").id = a;
            document.getElementById("PLACEHOLDER").id = "squareBLANK";
        }
        else if (this.board[i][j+1] == "_") {
            this.board[i][j+1] = x;
            this.board[i][j] = "_";
            document.getElementById(a).id = "PLACEHOLDER";
            document.getElementById("squareBLANK").id = a;
            document.getElementById("PLACEHOLDER").id = "squareBLANK";
        }
        else if (this.board[i][j-1] == "_") {
            this.board[i][j-1] = x;
            this.board[i][j] = "_";
            document.getElementById(a).id = "PLACEHOLDER";
            document.getElementById("squareBLANK").id = a;
            document.getElementById("PLACEHOLDER").id = "squareBLANK";
        }
        else if (this.board[i-1][j] == "_") {
            this.board[i-1][j] = x;
            this.board[i][j] = "_";
            document.getElementById(a).id = "PLACEHOLDER";
            document.getElementById("squareBLANK").id = a;
            document.getElementById("PLACEHOLDER").id = "squareBLANK";
        }   
    }


    }

    function startPuzzle() {let A = new Puzzle();}
```

So, can anyone tell what's preventing the squares from moving?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a `board Array` of `4 object`

```
this.board = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, "_"]];
```

And you setting your `squareBLANK slide method` parameters 3**LastObject**, 3**Third Value**, this.id**squareBLANK**.

```
<div class="square" id="squareBLANK" onclick="A.slide(3, 3, this.id)">  </div>
```

In your Javascript you are checking [i]**LastObject** means **[3+1] = 4**. You actually check **3rd value** in **5th Object** in your **board Array** which is not exist and also it's returning **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined** in console.

```
if (this.board[i+1][j] == "_")
```